# destructured object not accesible in of statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, destructuring

My code looks like this
it's aiming to observe a modal content when it's open

```
const data = {
   modal: false,
   button: null
};

const updateData = () => {
   const {modal, button} = data

   if (document.querySelector('.modal')) {
       modal = true
       button = document.querySelector('.modalButton')
   }
};
```

I get the following error when I call `updateData()`:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: modal is not defined"

It works as intended when it's written like this:

```
const updateData = () => {

    if (document.querySelector('.modal')) {
        data.modal = true
        data.button = document.querySelector('.modalButton')
    }
};
```

I can't understand why destructured data isn't accessible in the if statement.

Comment: *it works as intended when it's written like this* It shouldn't. You forgot to try to try to assign the properties to the `data` object. Also, your lower code results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`. Is your `updateData` intended to be an object or a function?

Comment: what is this if statement evne supposed to do

Comment: It absolutely does not work as intended when you write it the second way...

Comment: sorry my bad, updateData is an arrowf function actually

Comment: Do you want updateData to be a function? Do you want the function to return an object?

Comment: You're not even apparently using the destructured values. It's really hard to tell what you're even trying to do to be honest

Comment: sorry I made several syntax errors in the example I gave, should be right now

Comment: You can not reassign modal and button after destructuring because you make them const and const can't be re assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to do, because you set the variables modal and button by destructuring them, and then you don't use those variables...

You can do something like this:

```js
const data = {
   modal: false,
   button: null
};

const updateData = () => {
   const {modal, button} = data

   if (true) {
     return {
       modal, button
     }
   }
};

console.log(updateData());
```

You cannot update properties of objects AFTER destructuring, by using the destructured variables, if that's what you're trying to do.

If you want to update `data.modal`, you'll have to do `data.modal = 'xx'`;